# Combo box component list not dropping down

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a combo box component in a frame with a list of 30 items. When I run it on my C drive, it works as it should. When I publish the .swf to a web server, the drop down list doesn't drop down -- just a green focus rectangle appears around the combo box which shows only the first list item. Has anybody seen this behavior before and can advise on how to fix it?

Crossdomain allows all domains, the SWF itself allows all domains, allowScriptAccess is allowed. Basically all the security has been turned it off and it still won't work properly on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply fixed this by adding `this._lockroot = true;` to the first frame.